# social media platform vs. social media venue

Tags: word-choice, internet, social-media

What would be the correct or most appropriate word for each social media form (e.g., Facebook, Twitter, Blog, etc.)

Social media platform?
Social media venue?
Social media account?

"Among multiple social media platforms, Facebook is most effective in ....."

Answer (score 1):

Platform is correct for what you want to say here.

A venue on the other hand is an actual physical place where events are usually held.

An account is the what people use to connect on the platforms - everyone needs their own account to join and do things.

Answer (score 0):

There are two common terms:

> [platform](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/software%20platform) — a major piece of software, as an operating system, an operating environment, or a database, under which various smaller application programs can be designed to run.

Within the scope of social media, a "platform" would be any piece of software that enables its users to engage in social media activities.

**Service** is also used to describe social media products that provide a set of services. These are referred to as "social media services" and would accurately describe the examples in your post.